# Mockito's mock not works in a runnable

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito

I'm using mockito with Spring Boot. I found the stubs not work when using the mocked object in a `Runnable`.

Here is the code sample:

```
@Component
public class TheClassIWantTest {
    @Autowired
    private ADependency aDependency;

    @Autowired
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor;

    public void theMethodIWantTest {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Integer result = aDependency.doSomething();  // result should be 111, but it's null
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The unit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestApplication.class)
@FixMethodOrder(value = MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class TheTest {

    @Autowired
    private TheClassIWantTest theClassIWantTest;

    @MockBean
    private ADependency aDependency;

    @Test
    public void testTheMethod() {
        Ingeter testResult = 1;
        when(aDependency.doSomething()).thenReturn(111);  // this stub doesn't work...

        theClassIWantTest.theMethodIWantTest();
    }
}
```

I was expecting `aDependency.doSomething()` would return `111`, because I defined the stub in the test case, but the `result` is null.

And if I remove the lines of

```
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
```

to turn the async runnable method to a normal sync method, the stub works good,e.g `result == 111`.

This makes me think the stubs don't work anymore in a runnable.

How can I fix this? Or is there a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you check anything about the result in your test? Why do you call this method (or why does it return an Integer), since you're not doing anything with the result?

Comment: @JBNizet The code sample is a highly abstract of real business logicals. In real business logicals, `aDependency.doSomething()` will make a http request to one remote service. According to the result of this remote call, some crucial log will be printed into a offline analysis log file, my test case will verify these log entries.

Comment: The thing is that you've removed so much of your code (production and test) that it doesn't make sense anymore. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered that your test may actually be running faster than your Runnable? The executor service is asked to run the Runnable code and will do that in a separate thread (taken from a ThreadPool). Meanwhile, your test class continues on the main thread. You may want to look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html that will allow you pause your test code until your business code has counted down on your latch. Note that you are modifying your business code to accommodate for testing. Unit testing multi-threaded code is never easy...